# How do I turn a form into a attachable file for email in php

Tags: php, file, email

So I Have a form that will send out emails that correspond to how they filled the form.  I have to take some information that was filled in the form and put it in a HTML form to send in a email which is done in php.

My question is, is there anyway to turn that form into a attachable file that could just be added to the mail function and sent instead?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what kind of file? why not send the details in the email body ?

Comment: So you want to convert the form to something like a PDF, attach and send?

Comment: Whats better pdf or text file? - @Dagon would it be easier to just add it into the body?

Comment: i see no reason for an attachment in this case. and yes it would be easier to just put the text in the email body.

Comment: P.S your use of form (html <form>) and form (=format) is a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can transform your HTML form into a... HTML page (using HTML tokens manually, or maybe something like TCPDF?), and save it to a temporary disk file, then attach it to the outgoing email. Of course, your mail function must support attachments! (If it doesn't, use a different mailer functions - there's many of them).

You can do it quickly by preparing the form manually and replacing the text fields with something like `{{ Name }}`.

Then just run a `str_replace` on the `file_get_contents()` of your template and save the results in a temporary file:

```
 $translate = array(
     '{{ Name }}'    => $Form['Name'],
     ....
 );
 // one could also use preg_replace with 'e' flag and use directly $Form...
 $html = str_replace(array_keys($translate), array_values($translate),
            file_get_contents("form-template.html"));
```

In just the same way you can prepare a Word document, save it as RTF (which is ASCII readable), and attach the file with .doc extension -- most word processors will open it automatically.

If you want to send a PDF file (using TCPDF, FPDF, etc.), it's a bit more complicated but not too much.

Answer (score 0):

[Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) integrates into any web app written in PHP 5, offering a flexible and elegant object-oriented approach to sending emails with a multitude of features including attachments.

Comment: Thanks but I think I'll stick to just putting it into html form. Will check it out though!